# What is a good method to set a state that will be changed based off a useQuery without the deprecated onSuccess call back?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I originally used the code below to set my components state, but I have seen online that

1. It's a bad method to set a component's state as it can introduce bugs
2. The callbacks on useQuery will be deprecated

So my question is what is the best method to set a state that will be changed once received depending on the users actions with its original source coming from the useQuery?

I only want it to set the state once from the useQuery

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(null);
 
const stateQuery = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['deviceGetStateAPI', deviceid],
  queryFn: () => deviceGetStateAPI(deviceid),
  onSuccess: data => {
    if (!state) {
      setState(data)
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: What is `setDisplaySettings()`? Did you mean `setState()`?

Comment: I don't know about "best method", but I will let you know it's a general React anti-pattern to duplicate state into local state, just use the fetched/queried `data` value directly and then you don't need to worry about state synchronization issues.

Comment: @DrewReese I assumed OP wanted to make changes to the state after initial loading. Could be wrong though

Comment: @Phil That's about the only exception to the "general rule". 

Comment: @Phil Yes I was going to change the state after I got the displaySettings from the api

Answer (score 0):

You can find a state-mirroring example in the [v5 migration docs](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/guides/migrating-to-v5#removed-keeppreviousdata-in-favor-of-placeholderdata-identity-function).

The general idea is to use an effect hook to monitor and synchronise query data state with local state

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(null);
 
const { data, error, isPending } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['deviceGetStateAPI', deviceid],
  queryFn: () => deviceGetStateAPI(deviceid),
  onSuccess: data => {
    if (!displaySettings) {
      setDisplaySettings(data)
    }
  },
});

useEffect(() => {
  setState(data); // or setDisplaySettings(data) ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
}, [data]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's separate the query from your React Component.

```
// useDevice.js
const useDevice = ({deviceId}) => {
    const { data, error, ...queryResponse } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ['deviceGetStateAPI', deviceId],
        queryFn: () => deviceGetStateAPI(deviceId)
    })

    return { deviceInfo: data, error } // queryResponse.isLoading, queryResponse.isFetching.
}
```

Now your React Component

```
const DeviceDetail = () => {
const { deviceInfo, error } = useDevice({deviceId: 12314})

if (error) { 
    // handle error properly
}

return <DeviceDetails deviceInfo={deviceInfo} />
```

Ideally, this is the best way to do it, you don't need a separate state piece to hold the response of useQuery.
**useQuery.data is in reality React.useState hook.**